# jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: jquery, api

I keep on getting this message on console using `codepen:jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

My javascript code :

```
var api_key = "fa15d403d0ab55e3cfd6e0867bbb0114";
$(document).ready(function(){
  var loc;
  //Call the location   
$.getJSON('https://ipinfo.io', function(data){
  loc = data.loc.split(",");
  console.log(loc);
 });
  $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + loc[0]  +  '&lon=' + loc[1] + '&APPID='+ api_key, function(weather){
         console.table("c ,",weather);
          });
});
```

Comment: what do you see in console when `console.log(loc);`

Comment: The '''loc' means location, so it console log the latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 1):

It means you're trying to read the `0` property of an `undefined` object.

Based on the code you shared, that's happening here: `loc[0]` - `loc` is undefined, so it's throwing the error.

The reason it's undefined is because of asynchronous ordering - your first function hasn't executed the callback yet where it's setting `loc`. Try putting the second call *inside* the first function (right after your `console.log` call) instead of after it.